# Using .I to return row numbers with data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

Would someone please explain to me the correct usage of `.I` for returning the row numbers of a data.table?

I have data like this:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(X=c(5, 15, 20, 25, 30))
DT
#     X
# 1:  5
# 2: 15
# 3: 20
# 4: 25
# 5: 30
```

I want to return a vector of row indices where a condition in `i` is `TRUE`, e.g. which rows have an `X` greater than 20.

```
DT[X > 20]
# rows 4 & 5 are greater than 20
```

To get the indices, I tried:

```
DT[X > 20, .I]
# [1] 1 2
```

...but clearly I am doing it wrong, because that simply returns a vector containing 1 to the number of returned rows. (Which I thought was pretty much what `.N` was for?).

Sorry if this seems extremely basic, but all I have been able to find in the data.table documentation is WHAT `.I` and `.N` do, not HOW to use them.

Comment: Do you have a sample dataset?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: @WetFeet updated with example

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If all you want is the row numbers rather than the rows themselves, then use `which = TRUE`, *not* `.I`.

```
DT[X > 20, which = TRUE]
# [1] 4 5
```

That way you get the benefits of optimization of `i`, for example fast joins or using an automatic index. The `which = TRUE` makes it return early with just the row numbers.

Here's the manual entry for the `which` argument inside data.table :

> `TRUE` returns the row numbers of `x` that `i` matches to. If `NA`, returns
>   the row numbers of `i` that have no match in `x`. By default `FALSE` and the
>   rows in `x` that match are returned.

---

#### Explanation:

Notice there is a specific relationship between `.I` and the `i = ..` argument in `DT[i = .., j = .., by = ..]`
Namely, `.I` is a vector of row numbers of the subsetted table.

```
### Lets create some sample data
set.seed(1)
LL <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, TRUE)
DT <- data.table(X=LL)
```

#### look at the difference between subsetting the whole table, and subsetting just `.I`

```
DT[X == "B", .I]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

DT[  , .I[X == "B"] ]
# [1]  1  2  5 11 14 19
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In hindsight it makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful example.  Is it correct to think of this as an order of operations issue?  With `DT[i=.., j=..,` the `i` operation happens first, right?  When `j` is evaluated, it's working on the subsetted table and the original row numbers are "lost".

Comment: Nowadays you can do `DT[X > 10, which = TRUE]`

Comment: `DT[X > 20, which = TRUE]` ... What other secrets are there regarding data.table? I would like knowing them *all*. data.table is the best piece of software I have ever seen.

Comment: @mattdowle ^^^  :)

Answer (score 19):

> Sorry if this seems extremely basic, but all I have been able to find in the data.table documentation is WHAT .I and .N do, not HOW to use them.

First let's check the documentation. I typed `?data.table` and searched for `.I`. Here's what's there :

> Advanced: **When grouping**, symbols .SD, .BY, .N, .I and .GRP may be used
>   in the j expression, defined as follows.
>
> .I is an integer vector equal to seq_len(nrow(x)). **While grouping**, it
>   holds for each item in the group its row location in x. This is
>   useful to subset in j; e.g. DT[, .I[which.max(somecol)], by=grp].

Emphasis added by me here. The original intention was for `.I` to be used while grouping. Note that there is in fact an example there in the documentation of HOW to use `.I`.

You aren't grouping.

That said, what you tried was reasonable. Over time these symbols have become to be used when not grouping as well. There might be a case that `.I` should return what you expected. I can see that using `.I` in `j` together with both `i` and `by` could be useful. Currently `.I` doesn't seem helpful when `i` is present, as you pointed out.

Using the `which()` function is good but might then circumvent optimization in `i` (`which()` needs a long logical input which has to be created and passed to it). Using the `which=TRUE` argument is good but then *just* returns the row numbers (you couldn't then do something with those row numbers in `j` by group).

Feature request [#1494](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1494) filed to discuss changing `.I` to work the way you expected. The documentation does contain the words "its row location in x" which would imply what you expected since `x` is the whole data.table.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively,

```
 DataTable[ , which(X>10) ]
```

is probably easier to understand and more idiomatically R.