# How to change a variable at the nth occurrence of a value in another variable?

Tags: r, data.table

There is a data.table

```
library(data.table)
car <- data.table(no = 1:100, turn = sample(1:5,100,replace = TRUE), 
              dis = sample(1:10,100,replace = TRUE))
```

I want to change "dis" to -1, at the *n*th occurrence of `turn == 3`, say the third time that "turn" is `3`.

I can select the third row of `turn == 3`:

```
car[turn == 3, .SD[3]]
```

However, I don't manage to update "dis" at this row:

```
car[turn == 3, .SD[3]][, dis := -1]
```

A related Q&A: [Conditionally replacing column values with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536771/r-datatable-conditionally-replacing-column-values).

Comment: It is a matter of how to locate that row. Here is an alternative way similar to Henrik' scomment: `car[cumsum(turn == 3) == 3 & (turn == 3), dis := -1]`

Comment: correct. here's a similar: `car[(x <- turn == 3) & cumsum(x) == 3, dis := -1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some alternatives. Use `rowid` or `cumsum` to create a counter of rows within groups. Add the counter to your condition in `i`.

I use a slightly smaller toy data set, just to make it easier to track the changes:

```
d <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 1:12)

d[rowid(x) == 3 & x == 3, y := -1]

# @mt1022
d[cumsum(x == 3) == 3 & (x == 3), y := -1]

# @docendo discimus
d[(ix <- x == 3) & cumsum(ix) == 3, y := -1]
```

---

Although OP didn't mention speed as an issue, I was still curious to time the different approaches on a larger vector. Unsurprisingly, @Frank's method is the fastest, especially so when the number of unique values to search among increases:

`frank << docendo < henrik < mt022`

```
microbenchmark(henrik = d[rowid(x) == 3 & x == 3, y := -1],
               mt1022 = d[cumsum(x == 3) == 3 & (x == 3), y := -1],
               docendo = d[(ix <- x == 3) & cumsum(ix) == 3, y := -1],
               frank = d[d[x == 3, which = TRUE][3], y := -1], unit = "relative")

d <- data.table(x = sample(1:3, 1e6, replace = TRUE), y = 1:1e6)
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  henrik 4.417303 4.369407 4.133514 4.319839 4.329658 1.260394   100  b 
#  mt1022 5.461961 5.285562 5.174559 5.186404 5.239738 1.608712   100   c
# docendo 3.572646 3.624369 3.788678 3.589705 3.576637 1.733272   100  b 
#   frank 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100 a 

d <- data.table(x = sample(1:30, 1e6, replace = TRUE), y = 1:1e6)
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  henrik 22.64881 19.54375 18.81963 18.91335 19.78559 5.507692   100  bc
#  mt1022 24.58258 21.17535 19.84417 20.96256 22.76020 3.625263   100   c
# docendo 19.40044 16.75912 16.23321 16.47953 18.06264 4.234100   100  b 
#   frank  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000   100 a

d <- data.table(x = sample(1:300, 1e6, replace = TRUE), y = 1:1e6)
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#  henrik 31.81237 32.51122 28.79490 30.35766 28.63560  8.236282   100  b 
#  mt1022 34.71984 35.45341 33.20405 33.57394 31.50914 21.556367   100   c
# docendo 27.99046 28.15855 26.56954 26.60644 25.20044  7.847163   100  b 
#   frank  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.000000   100 a

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq        max neval cld
#  henrik 60.655582 76.455531 83.061266 77.632036 78.57818 203.224042   100   c
#  mt1022 66.701182 84.133034 87.967300 84.937201 85.72464 201.167914   100   c
# docendo 52.938545 67.214360 71.558130 68.003891 68.51897 184.178346   100  b 
#   frank  1.977821  2.494039  2.629852  2.663577  2.76089   3.613905   100 a
```

Comment: Thanks to edit the question.I can study how to ask next time.

Comment: @docendo discimus I included your nice suggestion in my answer. Please feel free to remove and post separate answer if you want.

Comment: @Frank ...`which` I didn't think of...Much better! Please post as answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Ah, your ping didn't connect / show up in my inbox for some reason. Thanks for adding the benchmark. I guess rowid can be implemented very efficiently. It's essentially the same as `sequence(.Ns)` jumbled, where `.Ns` are the sizes of each group; so it doesn't need to do any computation (like `cumsum` does by taking the running sum).

Comment: @Frank OK, yeah, makes sense. Now I just have to figure out how to save those `74.96846` milliseconds somewhere else. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
car[car[turn == 3, which = TRUE][3], dis := -1 ]
```

---

*Comment.* For an operation like this, you might want to turn `verbose` on, so you can see if any change was made. For example, if we look for the 111th 3....

```
car[car[turn == 3, which = TRUE][111], dis := -1, verbose = TRUE ]
# Detected that j uses these columns: dis 
# Assigning to 0 row subset of 100 rows
```

It shows that 0 rows were edited.

---

See also [Using .I to return row numbers with data.table package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408306/using-i-to-return-row-numbers-with-data-table-package) on the use of `which = TRUE`.