# How to return the row/s along with the row number/s in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to subset a data.table based on a condition but I want also to get its original row number/s from the data.table. What I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408306) is that you just need to set the `which` to `TRUE` but it only returns the actual row number not with its entire row.

`Boston[medv == min(medv), which=TRUE]` this one returns `[1] 399 406` which means that those row met the condition.

If `which` is not set to `TRUE`, i.e. `Boston[medv == min(medv)]` it returns

```r
      crim zn indus chas   nox    rm age    dis rad tax ptratio  black lstat medv
1: 38.3518  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.453 100 1.4896  24 666    20.2 396.90 30.59    5
2: 67.9208  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.683 100 1.4254  24 666    20.2 384.97 22.98    5
```

which it returns the row number differently (i.e. `1` & `2`).

What I'm trying to achieve is to look like this,

```r
      crim zn indus chas   nox    rm age    dis rad tax ptratio  black lstat medv
399: 38.3518  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.453 100 1.4896  24 666    20.2 396.90 30.59    5
406: 67.9208  0  18.1    0 0.693 5.683 100 1.4254  24 666    20.2 384.97 22.98    5
```

where the row number is `309` and `406`.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` doesn't use row names so I don't think what you are trying to achieve 
is possible. Instead you could just create a new column holiding the original row id.

```
irisDT <- data.table(iris)
irisDT[, rowid := .I][Sepal.Width == 3.5]


   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species rowid
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     1
2:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa    18
3:          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa    28
4:          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa    37
5:          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa    41
6:          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa    44
```

Comment: Suggest to use `copy` for iris to avoid overwriting it. Granted it can be recovered but best to copy.

Comment: @NelsonGon Don't know what you are talking about. `data.table()` is not the same as `setDT()`.